# How to randomize the order of buttons in a div?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a education website and I need some help.

I have this code:

```
    challenge1 = num1*num2;
    challenge2 = num1*2+Math.floor(Math.random() *3) + 1;;
    challenge3 = num1*num2+Math.floor(Math.random() *9) + 1;
    challenge4 = num2+Math.floor(Math.random() *9) + 1;

    makeButton(challenge1);
    makeButton(challenge2);
    makeButton(challenge3);
    makeButton(challenge4);
```

```
function makeButton(number) {
    btncount = btncount+1;
    /* create a button */
    var b = document.createElement('button');
    b.setAttribute('class', 'pure-button');
    b.setAttribute('onclick', `check(${number})`);
    b.setAttribute('id', btncount);
    b.textContent = number;

    var buttons = document.getElementById("buttons");
    buttons.appendChild(b);
}
```

`<div id='buttons' class="pure-button-group" role="group"></div>`

and it works but it's very easy to spot that the correct answer will always be the first button.

Is there a way to randomize the order of those? Thanks.

Comment: Put your buttons in an array and then shuffle them https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Comment: Put all your challenges in an array, then shuffle and a for each. You can use one of the many shuffle algorithms out there. A simple one is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: Try Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);

Answer (score 0):

It's about shuffling a list. you should create an array of elements first(without appending them to the parent), shuffle it, and then `parent.append(...list)`.

You can find out how to shuffle a list here:
[How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Answer (score 0):

You could make an array of challenges and sort this array with a custom comparator:

```
   challenges = [
     num1*num2,
     num1*2+Math.floor(Math.random() *3) + 1,
     num1*num2+Math.floor(Math.random() *9) + 1,
     num2+Math.floor(Math.random() *9) + 1
   ]
   function randomizer () { return Math.random() > 0.5 }
   challenges.sort(randomizer)

   for (challenge of challenges) makeButton(challenge)
```

---

**EDIT**
To have a better randomization you can make a list of object with a random index and sort it normally:

```
   challenges = [
     { challenge: num1*num2, index: Math.random() },
     { challenge: num1*2+Math.floor(Math.random() *3) + 1, index: Math.random() },
     { challenge: num1*num2+Math.floor(Math.random() *9) + 1, index: Math.random() },
     { challenge: num2+Math.floor(Math.random() *9) + 1, index: Math.random() }
   ]

   function compare(a,b) { return a.index == b.index ? 0 : a.index > b.index ? 1 : -1 }
   challenges.sort(compare)

   for (i in challenges) makeButton(challenges[i].challenge)
```

Comment: Your solution works, but it isn't entirely "random". I mean, I've observed that there's a very high chance that the correct answer is the first button. Is there a way to make it even more random?

Comment: The first randomizer has 50% chances to move an item in the array.
Check the edit, it sets a random index for each challenge and sort the table on this random index.

Answer (score 0):

following your snippet you can swap first and last randomly

```js
let btncount = 0;
function makeButton(number) {
  btncount = btncount+1;
  /* create a button */
  var b = document.createElement('button');
  b.setAttribute('class', 'pure-button');
  b.setAttribute('onclick', `check(${number})`);
  b.setAttribute('id', btncount);
  b.textContent = number;

  var buttons = document.getElementById("buttons");
  buttons.appendChild(b);
  //randomly swap first and last
  if(Math.round(Math.random())) {
    // swap first and last
    buttons.appendChild(buttons.firstElementChild);
  }
}

const num1 = 1, num2 = 2;
const challenge1 = num1*num2;
const challenge2 = num1*2+Math.floor(Math.random() *3) + 1;;
const challenge3 = num1*num2+Math.floor(Math.random() *9) + 1;
const challenge4 = num2+Math.floor(Math.random() *9) + 1;

makeButton(challenge1);
makeButton(challenge2);
makeButton(challenge3);
makeButton(challenge4);
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the "challenges" into an array and shuffle it. You can shuffle in plain javascript as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6274381/11653883), but I prefer to shuffle with [rando.js](https://github.com/nastyox/Rando.js), like this:

```js
console.log( randoSequence(["a", "b", "c"]) );
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/2.0.0.js"></script>
```

Apply that shuffle to your buttons, and you have this:

```js
var num1 = 2;
var num2 = 4;
var btncount = 0;

challenge1 = num1 * num2;
challenge2 = num1 * 2 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;;
challenge3 = num1 * num2 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
challenge4 = num2 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;

//------------CHANGED PART------------
var shuffledChallenges = randoSequence([challenge1, challenge2, challenge3, challenge4]);

makeButton(shuffledChallenges[0].value);
makeButton(shuffledChallenges[1].value);
makeButton(shuffledChallenges[2].value);
makeButton(shuffledChallenges[3].value);
//--------END OF CHANGED PART.--------

function makeButton(number) {
  btncount = btncount + 1;
  /* create a button */
  var b = document.createElement('button');
  b.setAttribute('class', 'pure-button');
  b.setAttribute('onclick', `check(${number})`);
  b.setAttribute('id', btncount);
  b.textContent = number;

  var buttons = document.getElementById("buttons");
  buttons.appendChild(b);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/2.0.0.js"></script>
<div id='buttons' class="pure-button-group" role="group"></div>
```